# Best application IDE to use for Java debugging

Tags: java, debugging

I have recently been teaching myself Java code and am looking for a debugging program so I can identify breakpoints and errors in my code. I am on a Windows OS and have some familiarity with Eclipse, but I'm unsure.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any major Java IDE will be suitable for debugging of Java code. If you are familiar with Eclipse, try that. Or you can also try to evaluate the different IDEs for other purposes, if you have any specific requirements, but the baseline is that for Java debugging any IDE will be suitable.

Comment: Thanks. I went with NetBeans IDE. Works well.